# Condition coverage for If(A && B) - measuring the input or code exercised?

Tags: testing, test-coverage, conditions

I have been studying condition coverage for last few days. In a book "The Art of Software Testing" they highlight that it does not assure decision coverage, because for example

> IF(A && B)

`A=True, B=false` and `A=False,B=True` satisfies the condition coverage but the decision is always `False`.

I wonder, how can this satisfy the coverage? The `True` value of `B` will actually never be tested because of short circuiting so how it can satisfy the coverage?

Answer (score 11):

Condition coverage is about testing that any operands which are part of the `if` expression can be evaluated to both `true` and `false` without issues. In this type of coverage, you don't care about what would be executed inside the braces, nor about the result of the operand used in a condition.

Take the following code:

```
bool a = ...;
bool b = ...;
if (a && b)
{
    ...
}
```

Condition coverage of this code would require to test:

- `a` for both true and false, and:
- `b` for both true and false.

**In languages which require both operands to evaluate in a logical operation**, condition coverage of the code above is satisfied with:

```
a = true; b = false
a = false; b = true
```

This is what is illustrated in your question.

**Some languages evaluate the second operand of a logical AND only if the first operand is true** (or evaluate the second operand of OR only if the first operand evaluates to false). In this case, three tests are required instead of two:

```
a = true; b = true
a = true; b = false
a = false
```

As you can note, we don't care about the value of `b` in the third test, since the program will never compute it when `a` is false.